# WordPress - using sessions?

Tags: functions, customization

http://diovo.com/2009/10/using-sessions-in-wordpress/

This is working on one blog,but not on other,what could be the problem? How to find what is a problem?

Tnx in advance

Comment: How is it not working? What happens? And did you try to use the init hook to start your session?

Comment: @Bainternet How do you mean how is ti not working? :) I done everything like in link that I paste in my question,and it is working on one project but not on second.How to make it work on both projects?How to find what is the problem?

Comment: Ok then a different question,  is it the same host?

Comment: @Bainternet, nope it is not same host.

Comment: Ok , this is progress,  check if session mod is enabled at your server

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to add your `session_start();` to the top of your header.php file if you're planning to use it in your theme.

If you are wanting to use a session in the admin, I'd recommend either passing variables through `$_GET` or `$_POST`.  Also, if you need long term storage of variables, it's pretty easy to store things in the options table.  See the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

Comment: Hi,tnx for response,will try to add to header to see is it working that way.

Comment: nope,now it doesnt work on either of my two blogs.